# How to duplicate all routes as a pretend subdirectory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

To create a mobile version of a site I would like to reuse my controllers, some views etc. but create what looks like a subdirectory for a mobile version. So you could have URLs like:

```
       /Controller/Action/Id
/mobile/Controller/Action/Id
etc.
```

These routes would ideally map to the same controller and then I could look somewhere like in the route data to see if the URL is a mobile one. It would be good I can use `@Html.ActionLink()` etc. within a view and by default stay on either the mobile or desktop version without having to specify this, but have the ability to force one or the other.

I can achieve something like this by having an optional parameter on the front of every route, e.g.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{mobile}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, mobile = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new { mobile = "mobile|" }
      );
```

This then works as expected:

```
Takes you to either / or /mobile version depending on where you are currently:
@Html.ActionLink("Current", "Index"); 

/ version
@Html.ActionLink("Desktop", "Index", new { mobile = "" });

/mobile version
@Html.ActionLink("Mobile", "Index", new { mobile = "mobile" });
```

However this seems like a really lame solution, because I don't really want to add that to the front of every route. Is there any nice way I can do this in a better way, for example adding the optional `/mobile` prefix to all routes and have this work correctly? Or alternatively is there a completely different way I could approach the whole problem which would make more sense?

Hope this isn't too vague, any advice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For incoming requests it's easy, you just need two set of ruotes, one set where all routes start with `mobile/`. The issue is in URL generation, and to solve it you need to implement an [IRouteConstraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.routing.irouteconstraint) that act's on URL generation only and checks if the current route (of the current HTTP request) starts with `mobile/` or not, and compare that to the route being tested. I use a similar approach in the [MvcCodeRouting](http://mvccoderouting.codeplex.com/) library.

Comment: thanks, will have a look at this. You're right that the problem is only really in the generation - that's helpful thanks.

Answer (score 1):

have you seen this: http://51degrees.codeplex.com/

very good for having mobile/browser on the same codebase

Answer (score 1):

I've already perform this in a web project for asp.net mvc + jquery for "common" browsers and asp.net mvc + jqueryMobile for mobile browsers. I didn't need to create a new route in my global asax. Also these are a pretty sites for Mobile redirection:

[Mobile enabled web apps with ASP.NET MVC 3 and jQuery Mobile](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2011/02/25/mobile-enabled-web-apps-with-asp-net-mvc-3-and-jquery-mobile.aspx) (If you are using mvc3 is much easier)
[Walkthrough: Creating an ASP.NET MVC Areas Application Using Multiple Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee307987%28VS.100%29.aspx)
[A First Look at ASP.NET MVC 2](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/a-first-look-at-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx#multiproject-areas)

So, In my solution I used a Mobile Redirection Attribute, that I tag in my controller's actions that I wanna check for redirection. I saw that in your solution you "ask" the user to click the correct link, does depends on users and is not good (perhaps I didn't catch your intention). However, in this solution you check the for the user agent in the request, to know about the browser that perform the request to your site:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Attribute for Mobile Redirection when the request action comes from a mobile device.
    /// </summary>
    public class MobileRedirectAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        private const string defaultMobileController = "Mobile";

        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the action.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The action.</value>
        private string Action { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the controller.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The controller.</value>
        private string Controller { get; set; }

        private UrlHelper _urlHelper;
        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the URL helper.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The URL helper.</value>
        internal UrlHelper UrlHelper { set { this._urlHelper = value; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the last URL redirected.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The last URL redirected.</value>
        internal string RedirectedTo { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this instance is mobile device.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        ///     <c>true</c> if this instance is mobile device; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
        /// </value>
        internal bool IsMobileDevice { get; private set; }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether the specified controller is mobile.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="controller">The controller.</param>
        /// <returns>
        ///     <c>true</c> if the specified controller is mobile; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
        /// </returns>
        private bool IsMobile(Controller controller)
        {
            bool isMobile = controller.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice;
            string userAgent = controller.Request.UserAgent.ToLower();

            return (isMobile || userAgent.Contains("iphone") || userAgent.Contains("ipod") || userAgent.Contains("blackberry") || userAgent.Contains("mobile")
                             || userAgent.Contains("opera mini") || userAgent.Contains("palm"));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when [authorization].
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filterContext">The filter context.</param>
        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            Controller controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;
            this.IsMobileDevice = IsMobile(controller); //test porpouse
            if (this.IsMobileDevice)
            {
                this.RedirectedTo = GetUrlRedirectAction(filterContext.RequestContext);
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(this.RedirectedTo);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the URL redirect action.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="requestContext">The request context.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private string GetUrlRedirectAction(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            UrlHelper urlHelper = _urlHelper;
            if (urlHelper == null) //mocking porpouse;
                urlHelper = new UrlHelper(requestContext);

            return urlHelper.Action(this.Action, this.Controller, requestContext.RouteData.Values);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MobileRedirectAttribute"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="action">The action.</param>
        public MobileRedirectAttribute(string action)
        {
            this.Action = action;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MobileRedirectAttribute"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="controller">The controller.</param>
        /// <param name="action">The action.</param>
        public MobileRedirectAttribute(string controller, string action)
        {
            this.Action = action;
            this.Controller = controller;
        }

        #endregion

    }
```

So after this, the only thing you need to do is to tag your controller's actions that you wanna redirect to a different view. Controller logic can be refactor and extract it to a common method.

```
// GET: /MyController/
[MobileRedirectAttribute("MyController","IndexMobile")]
public ActionResult Index(string guid)
```

Hope to help, ask if you have any question.

Answer (score 0):

would this not work :

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Mobile", // Mobile route
                "mobile/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Default route
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

I believe that when a route is matched links create with ActionLink take into account the matched route and build the link for it?

I could be wrong though - I haven't actually tested it.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but the first (mobile) route will match when you use @Html.ActionLink() within the desktop part. also I would like to avoid this sort of duplication if possible.

Comment: No it wont- the desktop part will not match the mobile route as it does not contain mobile/ as part of its url. Unless I completly miss understand how the routing works, but Ive done rather alot with the routing in MVC for one of my apps.. use http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx to debug your routes - works a treat.

Comment: I mean the reverse matching, when you try to create a URL given a controller, action, and parameters. In that case you will always get the first route I think. Thanks for the link that looks really useful.

Comment: You get the first matched route I believe.. when adding routes to the global.asax add the most specific at the top moving down to your catch alls at the end. If it was that blind and just build for the first route then it wouldn't be all that powerful. - so its the first matched route.. which in case of desktop will be the last one above.. in case of mobile will be the first.

Comment: Just done a quick test and it seems I was wrong.. it is matching mobile/ - I'll let you know once I work out what it should be.

Comment: http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/03/removing-route-values-from-linksurls-in.html - might help a bit.